# Cannot find equivalent tooling in Azure API Apps using VS 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-app-api

I am using [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-App-Service-API-Apps-with-Scott-Hunter) as a reference. It is basically explaining how to build Azure Api Apps using VS 2013. I want to do the same in VS2015 and have installed the latest Azure SDK. I am finding the following things missing and not able to find its equivalent in VS2015 or any documentation that says how its done differently using VS 2015

Here are a list of the things that I was not able to find:

1. At 4.58 into the video the option to right click and convert a regular Web Api app into a Azure App Api.
2. At 5.23 the apiapp.json file is no longer available in a VS 2015 Api App project. What if I want to change the swagger url? Where do I configure that?
3. At 12.13 into the video there is an option to generate an Azure Api App client. I could not find this either in VS 2015. All I have is this below[image]

Am I bound to only provide urls for published API? What if I moved the API to a different URL later? I have not been thru this process yet so my next question is where do I configure the URL, which can possibly change as I move from DEV all the way thru to PROD.

Is there something missing in my tooling? Do I need to install something else other than the latest Azure SDK? How do I do those three items if my azure tools are up to date. I am using `Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40518.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in December 2015, Microsoft made several changes/improvements to API Apps ([they are listed here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/)).

1-This feature no longer exist, you need to add the Swashbuckle nuget package manually.

2-The apiapp.json file is no longer used.  Look for the SwaggerConfig.cs class in the App_Start folder.

3-The option has been renamed.  Right-Click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Add/REST API Client...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With regards to #2, I checked out the entire SwaggerConfig.cs class. I couldn't recognize what to un-comment to be able to customize the swagger url. I don't want to call it swagger. I'd like to have it renamed to `help/v1` or something like that.

Comment: with regards to #3, I tried out the add rest api client option, but all it told me was to provide the swagger url. I entered `swagger/docs/v1` but the [OK] button was still grayed out. The other option was to enter the path to the Swagger meta data file. I could not find that file. Coming back to the Swagger url, there is a button to select an Azure Asset. This points me to a subscription that I need to select. What if I have not yet published my service to Azure and I am still working on my dev box. Will this not work until I have deployed my service to Azure? Whats the reasoning for that?

Comment: #2-You need to specify a custom route.  A simple Google search lead me to this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#custom-routes

Comment: #3-This option is for generating the *client* code, not the API code.  You provide the API url and the Visual Studio tooling uses AutoREST to generate the client code.  You can point to a localhost while developing.

Comment: Thanks for point #2. I will check it out. With regards to #3, I know its for generating client code. I thought I would be able to provide a url to my locally hosted rest api and the framework would generate a client for me, much like in the good ol WCF days where a utility created a soap proxy for you in C#. Right now it seems that the only url I can provide is one that is of an API that is already published to Azure. I cant enter the url to my local API which is still under development. Will update my question with a screenshot.